# Ошибка при импорте встроенных модулей Python

Tags: python, импорт

Собственно сам код ошибки. Не могу понять причину. Вчера ругался на импорт модуля "re", а сегодня вот на fnmatch

```
>>> import fnmatch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\smbek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\fnmatch.py", line 15, in <module>
    import functools
  File "C:\Users\smbek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\functools.py", line 22, in <module>
    from types import MappingProxyType
ImportError: cannot import name 'MappingProxyType'
```

Comment: убедитесь что у вас нет собственного файла `types.py` либо в текущей директории или в тех дир-ях, кот. прописаны в `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: Гениально! Спасибо большое! Оказывается types.py в текущей директории находился)))

Comment: достаточно часто подобная ошибка встречается: [The name shadowing trap](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap)