# Проблема с установкой Pillow на Python 3.6: ImportError: cannot import name 'Image'

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, установка, pillow

Использую Windows 10 x64, Python 3.6

Установка Pillow с помощью pip (`pip install Pillow`) проходит без ошибок, однако при попытке импорта Image (`from PIL import Image`) появляется ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming\PIL.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "d:\programming\PIL.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ImportError: cannot import name 'Image'
```

Список установленных пакетов: *olefile (0.44), Pillow (4.2.1), pip (9.0.1), setuptools (36.5.0), wheel (0.30.0)*

Comment: связанный вопрос [Ошибка при импорте встроенных модулей Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/662046/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас скрипт назван так же, как модуль. При импорте python ищет `Image` не в модуле `PIL`, а в вашем скрипте. Так как там его нет, вы получаете ошибку.

Comment: имя модуля, когда он исполняется как скрипт всегда `__main__`. Проблема в том, что при исполнении скрипта его директория добавляется в `sys.path`, поэтому при попытке импорта `from PIL import Image` *происходит импорт PIL модуля* из текущей директории (`D'\Programming`). Решение это не меняет: следует переименовать модуль, чтобы его имя не конфликтовало с установленной библиотекой.