# AttributeError: module 'token' has no attribute '__all__' В чем заключается ошибка? Python 3.6 с подключенной telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Код:

```
import telebot
import tok

bot = telebot.TeleBot(tok.token)

bot.send_message(198175574, "test")
```

Ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "B:/Program Files/pyCharm/new1/kek1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import telebot

File "B:\Program Files\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import threading

 File "B:\Program Files\python\lib\threading.py", line 7, in <module>
    from traceback import format_exc as _format_exc

File "B:\Program Files\python\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache

File "B:\Program Files\python\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize

 File "B:\Program Files\python\lib\tokenize.py", line 41, in <module>
    __all__ = token.__all__ + ["COMMENT", "tokenize", "detect_encoding",
AttributeError: module 'token' has no attribute '__all__'
```

Помогите чайнику :(

Comment: `tok.token` или не модуль, или наоборот. В общем, похоже на несоответствие типов передаваемого и ожидаемого.

Comment: все было из-за того, что в директории был файл с именем "token". Но все равно спасибо

Comment: Если в import tok Вы передаете именно токен, то лучше просто написать TOKEN="ваш токен" bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

Comment: @jfs, ответы - в ответы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> AttributeError: module `'token'` has no attribute `'__all__'`

Вы `token.py` файл свой создали, который конфликтует с этим модулем из стандартной библиотеки([name shadowing trap](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap)). [Ошибка по той же причине](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/662046/23044). Есть IDE, которые предупреждают о таких конфликтах.